# Google Sheets' query + IFS function

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, ifs

I want to use `IFS` and Query in google sheet at the same time.

[image]

### Works Well

```
=QUERY('PN Orders'!A1:AF,"SELECT C, D where C LIKE '%" & $B$1& "%' and D LIKE '%" & $B$2& "%' LIMIT " &$B$3,1)
```

above query works well, get results. 
But every time I combine it with IFS function, it returns nothing.

### Doesn't work

```
=ifs( and($B$1<>"",$B$2<>"")=true, QUERY('PN Orders'!A1:AF,"SELECT C, D where C LIKE '%" & $B$1& "%' and D LIKE '%" & $B$2& "%' LIMIT " &$B$3,1))
```

Is there something I'm missing here? 
Why the query returns nothing when combined with `IFS` function?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to use QUERY as argument of IFS. Could you explain briefly why you are trying to do this instead of extenging the where clause of QUERY?

Comment: the name or the phone number can be empty. I somehow thinks that the query inside gsheet returns all values from all name, and then filtered it with the phone if the name is empty. So I think just play it safe. 
Please correct me if I'm wrong. 
- is there a better query syntax for me ? 
- is what I'm worrying doesn't make sense ? 
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IFS` is "array kind of type" formula. what you need in your scenario is simple `IF` statement:

```
=IF((B1<>"")*(B2<>""),
 QUERY('PN Orders'!A1:AF, 
 "select C,D 
  where C like '%"&B1&"%' 
    and D like '%"&B2&"%' 
  limit "&B3, 1), "enter name and phone")
```

[image: 0]

---

or perhaps like this:

```
=IF((B1<>"")+(B2<>""), 
 QUERY('PN Orders'!A1:AF, 
 "select C,D 
  where C like '%"&B1&"%' 
    and D like '%"&B2&"%' 
  limit "&B3, 1),  "enter name or phone")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem on your second formula is that is mixing a scalar comparison (single value) with an array of values when both arguments should be of the same type.